# How to share a variable among clusters in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am running my express application with clusters.
My master has some kind of caching with a variable that needs to be shared across my workers.
Can i do this in the following way as using a physical datastore is not feasible for me ?

```
if (cluster.isMaster) {
    // Create a worker for each CPU
    global.my_cache_variable = 'xyz';
    console.log("Number of cpu cores", cCPUs);
    for (var i = 0; i < cCPUs; i++) {
        cluster.fork();
    }

    cluster.on('online', function (worker) {
        console.log('Worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' is online.');
    });
    cluster.on('exit', function (worker, code, signal) {
        console.log('worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' died.');
        cluster.fork();
    });
} else {
   //create server code here
   // and access the global cache variable with the workers
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Although you can do inter-process communication, I it's not easy and may not be what you want (sharing variable across processes).
Your best option is probably to externalize your cache store, e.g. a Redis store that all clusters can access. It can be on the same machine or another one. It will also help if you need to scale horizontally, as it will be shared by multiple machines.